# How do you use source tree to work on multiple branches of a repo simultaneously?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In sourcetree, When we clone a repo, looks like the directory that is created and subsequently becomes the workspace is named for the default branch say master. (need this verified )

If I have multiple branches that I want to work on simultaneously, is it correct to think i have to clone multiple times one for each branch into a branch specific local repository ? that way

How would I merge from one to the other locally ?
Say I had checked out master, featureA and featureB (based off featureA)
If then I needs to merge into featureA from featureB how is that done ?

Comment: Look into [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), this does exactly what you want.

Comment: To answer your other questions, you would have to push and pull between them and basically treat them as completely separate clones, because that is what they are, so any merging and rebasing between them will have to be done using push/pull as normal. With worktrees, you're essentially having multiple working folders against the same repository, so they all see the same history.

Comment: Like @LasseVågsætherKarlsen told you well, use the `worktree` feature of git that is done exactly for that. The only constraint is that you can't have the same branch checked out in 2 worktrees (but there is no real use of that)